# Grouping Recyclerview items based on date without using any library

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to group my android `RecyclerView` items with a header made based on date like this:

12-01-2006

item 1
item 2
item 3

13-02-2006

item 4
item 5
item 6

Need code for that. Is it possible in `listview` ?. if yes which one is better `listview` or `recyclerview`.

Comment: Use Expandable List view for this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Use recyclerview. See [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/add-header-to-android-recyclerview/). It will help you to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: which one is better listview or recyclerview on the basis of performance

Comment: @muraleedharan RecyclerView is more optimized than ListView. And RecyclerView gives you more controls. Hope it helps you.

Comment: why you don't want to use a library **(sombody's else code)**, but want to get a complete code **(sombody's else code)**? What is the difference? In any case you will do nothing by yourself.

Comment: Want to know any simple method,thats why i mentioned without library

Answer (score -1):

Use recycler view with custom adapter. refer this link for better explanation https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Here group by items not mentioned.